# Matching multiple lines except some lines

Tags: regex, templating

I'm trying to write a regex expression that matches all the text across multiple lines from one character to another *unless* the line starts with the first character. Then I want to **not** match across multiple lines until we get to a certain character.

So it's like an expression inside an expression.
Here's an example:

```
keyword =  [
    key = {value}
    key1 = [
        key2 = {balue}
        key2 = {balue}
    ]
]

keyword = [
    key = {value}   
]
```

I want to match everything inside the square brackets, except when it comes to key1. It needs to ignore everything inside the square brackets inside of key1 and then catch everything inside square brackets of the next keyword.

I have regex to match everything inside the square brackets:
`\[([\s\S]*?)\`
but it doesn't take into account the second set of square brackets. How can I make it take that into account?

Comment: So, where is your regex? What regex engine are you using? Could you show your attempt, say, on http://regex101.com?

Comment: Is your input limited to only one level of nested brackets or does your input allow for N levels of nested brackets? If it allows N nestings, this problem would become context-free and you wouldn't be able to use a regular expression to rigorously capture it.

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas It only allows for 1 level of nesting

Comment: @stribizhev Sorry about that. I added it

Comment: I will ask again: what language are you using? PHP? Then have a look at https://regex101.com/r/hD2pW3/2

Comment: @stribizhev I'm using Python. Thanks  for your help - i'll look at it

Comment: @CalebLewis: Please check this solution in Python, where I am matching all `key1 = [...]`s and removing them from the input string: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTVMtNFY2WVVVZEk

Answer (score 1):

use a special character that doesn't exist in your string, like this: '¬'
Then place it at points you want to run your regex. Then do [^¬]+yourregex[^¬]+